# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in BLL.dll

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

So I've a 3 tier application using a SQL connection and stored procedure to add to table in a database. I've the stored procedure set up as follows in my data access layer...

```
public bool CreateAccount(AccountModel newAccount)
    {
        bool retValue = false;
        try
        {
           using (SqlConnection cxn = new SqlConnection(cxnString))

            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddAccount", cxn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                SqlParameter FirstNameParam = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                FirstNameParam.Value = newAccount.FirstName;
                SqlParameter SurnameParam = new SqlParameter("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                SurnameParam.Value = newAccount.Surname;
                SqlParameter EmailParam = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                EmailParam.Value = newAccount.Email;
                SqlParameter PhoneParam = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                PhoneParam.Value = newAccount.Phone;
                SqlParameter Address1Param = new SqlParameter("@Address2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                Address1Param.Value = newAccount.Address1;
                SqlParameter Address2Param = new SqlParameter("@Address2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                Address2Param.Value = newAccount.Address2;
                SqlParameter CityParam = new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                CityParam.Value = newAccount.City;
                SqlParameter CountyParam = new SqlParameter("@County", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                CountyParam.Value = newAccount.County;
                SqlParameter AccountTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@AccountType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                AccountTypeParam.Value = newAccount.AccountType;
                SqlParameter InitialBalanceParam = new SqlParameter("@InitialBalance", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                InitialBalanceParam.Value = newAccount.InitialBalance;
                SqlParameter OverdraftLimitParam = new SqlParameter("@OverdraftLimit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
                OverdraftLimitParam.Value = newAccount.OverdraftLimit;
                SqlParameter AccountNumberParam = new SqlParameter("AccountNumber", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                AccountNumberParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(FirstNameParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(SurnameParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(EmailParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(PhoneParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Address1Param);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Address2Param);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(CityParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(CountyParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(AccountNumberParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(InitialBalanceParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(OverdraftLimitParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(AccountNumberParam);

                cxn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cxn.Close();

           }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

But i get this error when running program that refers to my logic layer. 
[image: ErrorMessage]`

I've tried using `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` method both before and after the execution of the query but it doesn't help.

There are no other connections or SQL commands set up at all yet, this is the only one.

Can't figure it out myself and after reverting to searching online.

Thanks

This is where the exception is launched, in the business logic layer...

```
namespace BLL
{
    public class bllAccountManager
    {
        public bool CreateAccount(AccountModel newAccount)
        {
            bool retValue = false;

            dalAccountManager dal = new dalAccountManager();
            try
            {
                retValue = dal.CreateAccount(newAccount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have added AccountNumberParam twice to the collection.

Comment: Oh my god is all I have to say!!!

Comment: Its a bummer you don't get a compiler warning about something like that.

Comment: Very true, especially when you're learning like myself.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = newAccount.FirstName`. There you go, no more sneaky duplicates and a lot less typing. Also, don't use `catch` just to `throw`. Also, use `using` for disposable resources like `cmd`... would you like to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccountNumberParam parameter has been added twice. The exception is kinda self explanatory, just have to find the culprit.